# Creating custom UITextView with UILabels as well as text in it

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I would like to create a custom `UITextView` with the ability to enter text in it, as well as programmatically adding some `UILabels` there that would act like text (I need to delete them with the 'backspace' button when the cursor comes near them).

This `UITextView` should be expandable and the labels can have different width.

Any ideas of how you can create this sort of thing, any tutorials or such?

Comment: @SpencerWong do you seriously think I didn't know it?

Comment: A bit like the iOS Mail app does with the "To" field? You enter an email and then it changes to a green label thing and you can delete it with pressing backspace.

Comment: @Fogmeister that's right! That's exactly what I want to achieve!

Comment: Hmm... I haven't seen any tutorials like that but I'm sure there must be some. I'll have a look. Other than that I can only think of creating it from scratch and rendering the text yourself.

Comment: @Fogmeister thanks! I'll be looking into this thing myself, let's hope we find some clue to it.

Comment: Depending on what the exact functionality is you can use CoreText to render text into a UIView. You can also find the rect that a substring occupies within the UIView and use that to render a label separately. You'd have to make it a keyboard delegate too to manage the inserting and deleting of text and labels etc...

Comment: @Fogmeister wow, sounds  really great. Thanks for your help! I'll post here with the results as I'm finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create textfield using this code.

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 40)];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
textField.placeholder = @"enter text";
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;    
textField.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:textField];
[textField release];
```

And for creating label you can use this code:

```
CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake( 10, 40, 100, 30 );
    UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: labelFrame];
    [label setText: @"My Label"];
    [label setTextColor: [UIColor orangeColor]];
    label.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
    [view addSubview: label];
```

and for deleting label when backspace tape use this method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
if ([string isEqualToString:@""]) {
NSLog(@"backspace button pressed");
[label removeFromSuperview];
}
return YES;
}
```

If the backspace button is pressed, then the replacementString(string) will have null value. So we can identify backspace button press using this.