# Creating Custom UIController for iOS step by step tutorial

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface

I have found so many custom cocoa controls in various sites, specially in http://www.cocoacontrols.com/, that is really helpful. Anyone can use those. But I want to know that is there any step by step tutorial to make my own Custom UI Controller ? Can you post some reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here... nice tutorial for creating custom control 
http://www.thinkandbuild.it/how-to-build-a-custom-control-in-ios/?goback=%2Egmp_121874%2Egde_121874_member_214742305

Comment: oh! that is really good-- I need more, may be I need to write one... :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. [Custom UITableView](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/how-to-design-a-custom-uitableviewcell-from-scratch/1292/)
2. [Custom UIView](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-a-5-star-rating-view)
3. [Custom UIScrollView](http://iky1e.tumblr.com/post/11284574668/tutorial-cool-uiscrollview-effects)
4. [Custom UIImageView](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uiimageview-animation/)
5. [Custom UITextView using UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622607/creating-custom-uitextview-with-uilabels-as-well-as-text-in-it)

Comment: Ray's basic rating controller is nice one. But if you browse http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls link, you might understand what I am expecting. 
your answer is also correct.

Comment: @sumon Yes you are right cocoacontrols has wonders.

Answer (score 0):

check this, it will explain from basic.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-tutorial-part-1

Comment: may be you don't understand my question.